# facebook application get the username using php api

Tags: php, facebook

i 've found using file_get_contents like

json_decode(file_get_contents('http://graphdotfacebookdotcom/'.$uid));

will make my application very slow to load, are there any methods to retrieve the username of the facebook user?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

You may use the facebook sdk for this.

```
$session = $facebook->getSession();

$me = null;
// Session based API call.
if ($session) {
  try {
    $uid = $facebook->getUser();
    $me = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
  }
}
```

To see the complete example https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/blob/master/examples/example.php

Comment: i 'dont know why i can't use getSession();

Comment: How should this help in the main question "will make my application very slow to load"?? Does php sdk work through magically speeded up internet?

Answer (score 2):

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
'appId'  => $APIappId,
'secret' => $APIsecret,
'cookie' => true
 ));
$facebook->api('/'.$uid);
```

Don't forget to include facebook.php at the top

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you use Facebook PHP SDK to get the details.
You can get the other basic information also without time consuming.

Comment: What would be changed with PHP SDK? Is it supposed to work faster? Obviously - not.

Comment: you are correct, we diverted the question. The speed depends on facebook response

Answer (score 1):

You can speed this up by requesting less information like so (in PHP):

```
$me = $fb->api('me', array('fields' => 'username'));
$username = (isset($me['username'])) ? $me['username'] : '';
```

and in the JS SDK like so:

```
FB.api('me', {fields: 'username'}, function() { console.log(arguments); });
```

Answer (score 0):

No. There's no way to speed it up.